# Is it true that when $r=s-1$ is summed from $0\to k$, then $s$ is summed from $1\to k+1$?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, binomial-theorem

So I'm doing the binomial theorem in class at the moment, and I was wondering; when proving the binomial theorem by induction, the following steps occur:

$$(a+b)^{k+1}=\sum_{r=0}^{k} {k\choose r} a^{k-r+1}b^{r}+\sum_{r=0}^{k} {k\choose r}a^{k-r}b^{r+1}$$ 
let $s=r+1$, hence $r=s-1$ and $$=\sum_{r=0}^{k} {k\choose r}a^{k-r+1}b^{r}+\sum_{s=1}^{k+1} {k\choose s-1}a^{k-s+1}b^{s}$$ $$={k \choose 0}a^{k+1}b^0+\sum_{r=1}^k{k\choose r}a^{k-r+1}b^r+\sum_{s=1}^k {k\choose s-1}a^{k-s+1}b^s + {k\choose k}a^0b^{k+1}$$ $$=\sum_{r=1}^{k} {k\choose r}a^{k+1-r}b^k +a^{k+1} + b^{k+1}$$ $$=\sum_{r=0}^{k+1} {k+1\choose r}a^{k+1-r}b^{r}$$

and I definitely need some clarification on why the last two steps are possible. I understand how the combination would become $\displaystyle {k+1\choose r}$, but I'm struggling to understand how $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{k} = \sum_{s=1}^{k+1}$ since $s\neq r$, unless they're made to be equal? But to me that wouldn't make any sense either since this would have complicated implications for the prior parts of the proof, would it not?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following simple trick: when $r$ is summed between $0$ and $k$, it means that
$$
0\leq r\leq k.
$$
Now put $r=s-1$. Substitute above and obtain
$$
0\leq s-1\leq k,
$$
or equivalently, isolating $s$,
$$
1\leq s\leq k+1.
$$

Comment: They actually do merge, although you have some typo; in the penultimate line your coefficient should be $\binom{k+1}{r}$. However, note that the change $r=s-1$ is only done to make appear another sum, and once this sum appears it does not matter how you call the ranging index. To clarify this, you could put, for example, $k=5$, and write explicitly the two sums, $\sum_r$ and $\sum_s$. Here $r$ and $s$ are just "labels", and these labels range over the same set.